# Angular 5 - Observable - set first value of Observable into formgroup

Tags: angular, forms, observable

I do have an Observable of Contacts in my onInit method and I also will set the first contact of the Observable into my form.
Has anyone a hint how to do this?

```
ngOnInit() { 
    let contactsObservable: Observable<Contact[]> = 
    this.contactService.getAllContacts();
    contactsObservable.subscribe(contacts => {
        this.contacts = contacts; 
    });

    this.form = this.fb.group({ 
                // this.contacts[0] does not work
      contact: [this.contacts[0], [Validators.required]] // how to get contact[0] into form for presetting
    });
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get contacts async. 
Value can be put when Observable return value.

```
ngOnInit() { 
   this.form = this.fb.group({ 
     contact: ['', [Validators.required]] 
   });
   let contactsObservable: Observable<Contact[]> = 
   this.contactService.getAllContacts();
   contactsObservable.subscribe(contacts => {
       this.contacts = contacts; 
       this.form.controls['contact'].setValue(this.contacts[0])
   });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Form patchValue to set the form, as **vincecampanale** pointed out better use  Smart/Dumb Components pattern with observable then in your component you can set

```
  @Input() set contactsList(contacts: any[]) {
    if (contacts) {
      this.form.patchValue({
        contact: contacts[0]
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is a neat way to do it. Learned something new. Upvoted :)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply put the initialization of the `form` in a `subscribe()`?

```
ngOnInit() {
    // ...
    // .take(2) to ensure that it will run only for the first value:
    contactsObservable.take(1).subscribe(contacts => {
        this.form = this.fb.group({contact: [this.contacts[0], Validators.required]];
    });
    // ...
}
```

Or you can initialize your form without `contact`, and add it later to the `FormGroup`.

This will by asyncronous, but you can set an `*ngIf` in your template like this:

```
<form *ngIf="form" ...>...</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, the form would be in a child component from the one where you get the data. Then you could use the [`async`](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) pipe to pass the `contactsObservable` directly to the form, and use the values synchronously.

However, in order to do it all in the same `OnInit` hook, the best way would be to provide a [`startWith`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-startWith) value to your `contactsObservable`. This will only be viable if you know what the first value will be in every case, and if you know that already, you may as well just instantiate the form control with a valid starting value:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({ 
  contact: [[ // some value ], [Validators.required]]
});
```

You *could* initialize the form in the subscription as Roland mentioned in the comments, but this would reinitialize your form every time the observable emits a value. Similarly, setting the value of the form control imperatively from within a subscription runs the risk of overwriting user-entered input or other funky behavior depending on how your service works.

Examples of this approach would look something like

```
contactsObservable.subscribe(contacts => {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    contacts: [contacts, [...Validators]]
  })
});
```

Or

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  contacts: [[], [...Validators]]
});
contactsObservable.subscribe(contacts => {
  this.form.get('contacts').setValue(contacts);
});
```

Note you could use [`setValue`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#setValue) or [`patchValue`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#patchValue) depending on what you need. But this approach is still faulty because it attempts to ignore the asynchronous nature of the data. *And* it will overwrite whatever is currently in the input, so if the data is updated while the user is typing, their input will be cleared and replaced, which could be frustrating. Plus you will need to handle clean up of the subscription.

---

The main reason this pattern doesn't work as expected is that you're treating the asynchronous value `contacts` as though it is synchronous. Just by unpacking it in the component and saving the value to a variable doesn't remove the asynchronous nature of the values arriving through the Observable. Check out [this resource](https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754) for more info on that.

In my opinion, your best bet is to extract the form into a separate component and take advantage of Angular's `async` pipe to pass your asynchronous data in.

Comment: Add an example  showing how to do this with the async pipe

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me Angular 6.x:

```
 import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
 @Input() artist: Artist;
 artistForm: FormGroup;
 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private artistService: ArtistService, private location: Location, private fb: FormBuilder)  { this.createForm(); }


 ngOnInit() {
 this.getArtist();
}

   createForm(){
this.artistForm = this.fb.group({
  ArtistName: ['', Validators.required]

 });
}


   getArtist(): void{
const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
this.artistService.getArtist(id).pipe(tap(artist => this.artistForm.setValue({ArtistName: artist.ArtistName}))).subscribe(artist => {
  artist = this.artist;
  });

}
```

Now the html:

```
   <h2>Artist Information</h2>
  <form [formGroup]="artistForm">
  <div class="form-group">
  <label class="center-block">Artist Name:

    <input class="form-control" formControlName="ArtistName">
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
class MyComponent {

    ngOnInit() { 
       this.form = this.fb.group({ 
         contact: ['', [Validators.required]] 
       });
       let contactsObservable: Observable<Contact[]> = 
       this.subscription = this.contactService.getAllContacts()
           .pipe(take(1))
           .subscribe(contacts => {
               this.contacts = contacts; 
               this.form.controls['contact'].setValue(this.contacts[0])
           });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

IMPORTANT: remember to unsubcribe.

Answer (score 0):

No need to unsubscibe when you use take(1) and I don't like your approach as in some cas (for exemple when you use ngrx and dispatch the first time) the first observed value will be "null" or an empty list as you are still waiting for the request response.

Again, in NGRX, your store exists but is empty in a first place. This will be the case everytime your observable is actually a BehaviuourSubject