# Make an Editable ReactiveForm with asynchronus Data

Tags: angular, asynchronous, input, angular-reactive-forms

I use angular CLI 1.6 and angularfire2.

I have this reactive form :

```
<mat-form-field style="width:100%" appearance="outline">
<mat-label>Description du traitement</mat-label>
<textarea matInput formControlName="description" ></textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```

And i want pre-populate the form with asynchronous data.

```
{{ (ppssToDisplay | async)?.traitement }}
```

ppssToDisplay is an observable. How i can do this ?

Comment: Populate it by recreating the formGroup, when the async data returns. Alternatively, call `setValue` or `patchValue` on the FormGroup.

Comment: Does this return anything? => `{{ (ppssToDisplay | async)?.traitement | json}}`

Comment: I must extract all the data in my typescript ?

Comment: @DavidR With that i have my value but how i integrate this in form ?

Comment: @Newbiiiie Can you try  `(ppssToDisplay.flatMap((data: any) => data.traitement);)` ?

Comment: I can't do that in my template?

Comment: @Newbiiiie You can have it as a object/variable in your component `.ts` file and can use it in your template?

Comment: yes i try set value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [setValue](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#setValue) on your form control in your observable like,

```
....subscribe(res=>{
  this.form.controls['description'].setValue(ppssToDisplay.traitement);
});
```

Also the [article](https://toddmotto.com/angular-2-form-controls-patch-value-set-value) is helpful for you to handle async data.

Comment: i write this in my initform ?

Comment: No you have to write your code in `subscribe()` of observable. I found a similar SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49052690/1817690

Comment: thant i watch this